# Modifying SASS output

Tags: sass, compass-sass

SASS prints css comments in a new line by default. There doesn't exist a option as far as I know that allows comments to appended to the line.

So, the block

```
body {
  background-image: url(.....); /** comment */
  color: white; /** comment */
}
```

is converted to

```
body {
    background-image: url(.....);
    /** comment */
    color: white;
    /** comment */
}
```

Is there a way to add custom formatting?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen this isn't possible. The best example I could find is this post from 2008 by the (then) maintainer of Sass: http://groups.google.com/group/haml/browse_thread/thread/bf7cd23989c1170d